# How find this continued fraction

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

let $x$ such this  Continued fraction
$$x=[0;1,3,5,7,9,11,13,\cdots]$$

How find the vaule of $x$.
(can see:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)

My try: I know this
$$e=[2;1,2,1,1,4,1,1,6,1,1,8,\cdots] $$and
$$\pi=[3;7,15,1,292,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,\cdots]$$
But for my problem,I can't find solve it.Thank you

Comment: This continued fraction is equal to $(e^{2} - 1)/(e^{2} + 1)$. Using this continued fraction one can prove directly that $e^{2}$ irrational and moreover that there are no integers $a, b, c$ such that $ae^{4} + be^{2} + c = 0$ unless $a = b = c = 0$. Hence this continued fraction is very important.

Comment: why? Thank you very much

Comment: From Hecke's answer you know that $x = (e^{2} - 1)/(e^{2} + 1)$. If $x$ were rational then $x$ would have a finite simple continued fraction which is not the case here. So $x$ is irrational and therefore $e^{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Again if $ae^{4} + be^{2} + c = 0$ then $e^{2}$ could be expressed as a quadratic surd (i.e. member of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ for some positive integer $d$) and hence $x = (e^{2} - 1)/(e^{2} + 1)$ would also be quadratic surd. Then $x$ would have a periodic simple continued fraction which is not the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Gauss's continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_continued_fraction):

[image]

This particular expansion is known as [Lambert's continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertsContinuedFraction.html) and dates back to 1768.

Comment: This function how prove it?

Comment: i have related proof for $\tan x$ which can be modified by putting $ix$ in place of $x$. Check http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/04/continued-fraction-expansion-of-tanx.html

Comment: This link can't open it,Thank you

Comment: i dont know link is working at my end.